# Python Bottle - Inline IF statements in Template

Tags: python, templates, bottle

```
Make = <SELECT name="where_make">
        % for make in makes:
            <OPTION value="{{make}}" 
            % if make == defaults['make']:
                selected="selected"
            % end
            >{{make}}</option>
        %end
```

How can I do this if statement on a single line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bottle's built-in template engine supports [inline if statements](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions):

```
<option value="{{make}}" {{!'selected="selected"' if make == defaults['make'] else ""}}>{{make}}</option>
```

Note the exclamation mark before the `selected="selected"` - it tells the template engine not to escape quotes.

Demo:

```
from bottle import SimpleTemplate

tpl = SimpleTemplate("""Make = <SELECT name="where_make">
        % for make in makes:
            <option value="{{make}}" {{!'selected="selected"' if make == defaults['make'] else ""}}>{{make}}</option>
        %end""")
print tpl.render(make='test', defaults={'make': 'test'}, makes=['test'])
```

prints:

```
Make = <SELECT name="where_make">
            <option value="test" selected="selected">test</option>
```

Hope that helps.